# Horizontally scroll two parallel code-blocks together

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, revision-history

There are places where we have a parallel view of posts. Most notably that I could think of are:

- Review *Suggested Edits* in *Rendered output* view. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27449597))
- Watch a post's revision history in *Side-by-Side* view. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64483431/revisions))

In those situations we might have a code-block with a horizontal scroll-bar. Scrolling one side of the post, doesn't parallelly scroll the other.

**Is there a way to make the two parallel code-blocks scroll horizontally together?** Similarly to some known diff tools.

This might make reviewing edits a bit easier, saving us to scroll both code blocks separately.

Comment: I don't think that as very useful as one really should make code to fit screen without horizontal scroll as part of the edit... so  while I see this feature-request useful it's probably not going to get so much support that company will even look at it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov remember that in this split view the space for the code-block is cut in half. So a code-block that appears with no problem in the question might get "chopped" in the split view. I agree that it's kind of a "minor" request, just thought it can be a nice little touch